# How do I keep init from pivot_root and stay in ramdisk?

Tags: linux, iso, initrd

in short, I was not satisfied with the available distros as they are either roo large or are missing the features I need ootb, I also want it to boot it into ramdisk, so I made my own ISO.
This ISO contains the isolinux bootloader, the linux kernel and the initrd which contains busybox and a few other tools.
Now the issue I'm having is that busybox init is trying to pivot_root and I haven't specified root, I also don't want to pivot as all I need is already in the ramdisk, however setting root=/dev/ram0 doesn't work(invalid partition/root) and it still causes a kernel panic

Under "Operation" in this [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/initrd.html) I want to get to step 5 and no further, I haven't found much yet, so I am asking here.

How would I prevent linux/busybox/init from trying to leave the ramdisk?

Comment: that depends. It is your software – hadn't you decided to roll your own, we might be able to help you, but we don't know how you roll your initrd, so we can't even take an educated guess. You're probably pretty ill-advised to build your own Linux distro instead of basing on a system to build one that fulfills your needs. That's what OpenEmbedded and Buildroot are for, but frankly, if you want a busybox system with an initrd, Alpine Linux would just work and allow you to add the software you need trivially.

Comment: I suppose alpine would work, though I did it mostly as a learning excercise, and as I said before, the initrd is just a busybox install with /etc/init.d/rcS going over S??* which only contain pseudofs mounts. it's as vanilla as it gets, I'm not smart enough to greatly modify anything, the greatest extent of which is a static binary. also while alpine is pretty small, I've got my iso down below 15mb

Comment: yeah, 15 MB (capital MB, not mb: these are Megabytes, not millibits!) are no real problem if you build your own openembedded image. A minimal Alpine Linux root file system (at low compression!) is 3.1 MB, so you're not really that great off compared to building on Alpine (just add the kernel and modules, and install the uefi kernel shim to have a bootloader).

Comment: by the time I've added nfsd, kernel modules, and a few more bells and whistles, I'm back to where I was with my own iso, I checked, the alpine minirootfs is ~8MB, while my initrd is ~8MB, then I have to add the kernel and bootloader and would you look at that: it's roughly the same size. also the 15MB iso was mostly because I was not using compression, and it seems I was being a dumbdumb because I'd built in an initrd into the kernel

Comment: but if you stuck with an established distro, that solves *a lot* of problems for you, including how to do updates should you ever need them, having a somewhat coordinated placement of configuration, and, definitely a large factor, having patched software so that it works with the rest of your system without you having to figure out what you need to do. "Do it yourself" isn't that attractive when you realize that you're not only the architect of your house, but also both the inhabitants as well as the janitor for all future to come! Building systems that follow conventions and that someone has…

Comment: … already tested, fixed, verified: that has a lot of appeal in reality. For cases where you *really* need something custom, there's time-proven systems with which companies build the images for their embedded systems – the aforementioned OpenEmbedded and Buildroot, as most prominent examples. They offer build systems from "list of software I want" to "image that I can write to internal flash", give you reproducibility (super important! Do you *really* know in 6 months what you did to make your image?) and dependency management (including generation of a software bill of materials).

Comment: look, I get it, I know that making your own is suboptimal, I know that established is better, that doesn't change the learning aspect I was most after, if I'll ever need updates I know how to do that, I compile software on a regular basis, most projects have RSS/Atom so I can follow new releases, I also rarely clean my build directories, so I am confident I could reproduce it in 6 months, worst case I extract the ramdisk and copy the configs, I also have already tried other established solutions and all have left me wanting with large filesizes or lacking features

Comment: this ISO will be running on an old laptop as a server on an airgapped network, I doubt updates would be of great import and what of reproducability if it's only a one-off? good practice perhaps, but low in my list of needs

Comment: I come from the exact opposite position, things like tiny sensor nodes in the field: all offline, but it's very important that you can build the same image today as in 2028, when you do the experiment again, and that you can add software in the next spin of the image as needed.

Comment: whelp, I sure don't find it had to statically compile a couple binaries and chuck 'em into an iso, I also understand the reproducability part as well, and I can solve that with a small shell script

Comment: really, it's cool what you're doing :) just a warning about "production use", if you will, that the things that are less "mechanic" than making an image boot are usually these that come back to bite you later – you don't need that, so I can only encourage you to do what you're doing and learn!

Answer (score 1):

so yes, it apears I was being a dumb-dumb, the problem was twofold: I had compiled the kernel with initramfs source files and I had two initrd's.

the first prevented the loading of the external initrd, while the second was a case of isolinux not liking dots ( . ) as I hadn't cleaned the iso root and had initrd and initrd.xz

now I just have to figure out how to getty on runit

here's the inspiration and basis of my project: [Nir Lichtman's video on *Making Simple Linux Distro from Scratch*](http://youtu.be/QlzoegSuIzg).